# NetSuite: WorldShop/OZLink overwriting NetSuite Shipping Price

Tags: netsuite

I've got an online store powered by Netsuite where I am charging customers a fixed rate for shipping. So we take an order, and we tell the customer the shipping is $10. (for example)

We use WorldShip to actually do our shipping, and so we then weigh the package, enter a weight, etc.

The problem is, whatever our shipping costs actually are from WorldShip are overwriting the amount we promised the customer, and then when we go to charge the card it can't because we're only authorized.

What's the best approach to fixing this? When charges are created, have custom scripts that run that take the amount from the Sales Order instead of the amount from the fulfillment record? Is there a way to have WorldShip only overwrite the shipping amount on offline orders and not on online orders?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For this scenario, we've created a custom transaction body field on the sales order called "Shipping Charge Exception".  This field holds the shipping amount that we've promised to the customer and automatically gets copied to subsequent invoices or cash sales.

Then we have a workflow on the creation of invoices and cash sales (Before Submit) that copies the value of the Shipping Charge Exception field into the Shipping Cost field on the invoice or cash sale.

The item fulfillment will still hold the actual shipping cost but the invoice or cash sale will get the amount promised to the customer.

Comment: Thanks Mike! I'm going to give this a shot.

Comment: Hey Mike, so I've created a custom field and it's populating on the sales order. How are you populating the same field in subsequent invoices and cash sales? I tried creating a workflow that runs on the creation of those, but I need to somehow refer to the sales order to get the value over, right?

Comment: I don't have anything in place to copy transaction body fields from sales orders to invoices.  It's my understanding that NetSuite takes care of this.  We actually count on that in many scenarios.  If you want it to be copied to item fulfillments, then you need to check that box as well when defining the field. but SO to INV should be automatic.  As for referring to the sales order from the invoice, you access the SO using the Created From record then selecting the field name.

Comment: Yeah, it did just copy it automatically. My fulfillment guy is testing things from WorldShip now end-to-end, so I think I'm all set. Will mark it as the answer once I get confirmation!